# Responsive Google Visualization with SVG text overlay

Tags: svg, google-visualization

I'm using Google's new "material" charts:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Material

I would like to overlay some text on a chart, but want to keep the result responsive.

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/cxjp00ng/3/

While that works okay, you see see from the JS that it's very fragile:

```js
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    $('#pct').clone().insertAfter('#chart g:eq(1)').show();
});
```

That's taking the SVG text and moving it to the proper position within the chart SVG so that it's behind the tooltips.

Is there a cleaner, more robust way to do this?

The text placement relative to the chart isn't always great on small displays either (sometimes colliding with the chart itself). Is there a better way to position/size it?